# Подсветка неправильного синтаксиса в notepadd++ при редактировании php

Tags: php

Работаю в notepad++. Он не подсказывает мне ошибки в моем коде так, как это делает к примеру php sandbox. Здесь он не подсказал о пропущенной кавычке. Как его можно научить?

```
<?php

$array['qwe'] = "123";
$array['qwe2342'] = "1432t23";
$array['q23rwe'] = "12rts3";
$array['qrewtwtrhwe'] = "12334qt";
$array['qwsbsdfe'] = "12etrhws3";

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

    print "$key - $value <br>;

}
```

Comment: phpStorm не вариант?

Answer (score 0):

1. Либо вы забыли сохранить файл в формате *.php.
2. Были невнимательны.

P.S. Проверено на только установленном Notepad++, ошибка подсвечивается.